# Different time_step input for LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build a encoder-decoder network to classify video data. Reading the Keras documentation for LSTM cells, it expects a fixed number of `time_step` to the cell. However, the data that I'm dealing with has different numbers of frames for each category. I think I can pick out the longest one and pad the rest with the beginning frames or the final frames but I think the model will be biased toward the ones with similar frames. Is there a way that I can feed input data with different `time_step` into an LSTM cell in Keras? I could put a `<start>` and `<end>` token at the beginning and the end of the sequence to tell the network when to make prediction, but I am not sure how to do that.

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Make separate networks for examples with same time steps.

Answer (score 0):

> Reading the Keras documentation for LSTM cells, it expects a fixed
>   number of time_step to the cell.

I don't know where you get this information but you can pass variable length sequence(variable time_step dim) for lstm.
[LSTM](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a374c93092341f24027f60ffe32d56d2bff29b83/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2051) class is a child of RNN class and keras RNN documentation says.

> This layer supports masking for input data with a variable number of
>   timesteps

In order to feed a variable length sequence into LSTM, the timesteps dimension should be `None`. E.g

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(None, 10)))
```